# While Loop using Dynamic Text Using an XML column - need to break when a value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I am writing a while loop on an XML column in a SQL database.

It dynamically loops through the data using a repeating index, this could be 10 or 100. I want to break the loop when the returned value is null. The reason being its a while loop within a while loop and the first index runs to 91 (I know this as i checked but could be 1, or 50 depending on XML) and the second index varies so 99% of time its 1 coverholder to 1 binder, but sometimes it could be a coverholder has 2,3 or 4 binders (up to mostly around 1)

The script below works I have set @id <= 91 and returns 91 coverholders, and within them coverholders one of them has 10 binders so I have the @secondId <=10

This returns 910 rows when I really only need it to loop through roughly 180 times instead of the 910 so is becoming quite slow.

I need it to from break from @Id if coverholder column is null and @secondid if binderUMR is null?

Can someone assist, as I have no idea other than put it all in  a table and remove from there at end.

```
-- LOOP THROUGH ID's
DECLARE @id INT 
DECLARE @SecondID INT 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @id = 1

WHILE (@id <= 10)
BEGIN
    SET @SecondID = 1

    WHILE @SecondID <=2
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @SecondID INT 

                    SELECT ' + CAST(@id AS varchar(MAX)) + ' AS ID, 
' + CAST(@SecondID AS varchar(MAX)) + ' AS Second_ID, 
 audit.value(N''(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="'+CAST(@id as varchar(MAX))+'"]/Name/text())[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)'') as [Coverholder],
audit.value(N''(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="'+CAST(@id as varchar(MAX))+'"]/pxResults[@REPEATINGTYPE="PageList"]/rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="'+CAST(@SecondID as varchar(MAX))+'"]/BinderUMR/text())[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)'') as [BinderUMR]

            FROM   
                #Dataset t
            CROSS APPLY 
                TransXML.nodes(''pagedata/Audit_DirtyList/pxResults[@REPEATINGTYPE="PageList"]'') AS pagedata(audit);
'
        EXEC (@SQL)

        SET @SecondID = @SecondID + 1
    END

    SET @id = @id + 1
END
```

I can't show the XML as its got important information, and I can't make one as a, I don't know how and b, I'm not sure how I could create one which would be this unique so hoping someone can give me basic principles and I can replicate.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You can obfuscate values in your XML sample

Comment: Any time you think you need to write some kind of loop in SQL Server... don't! Step back and think about the problem using set-based relational database techniques. e.g.: your iterators could come from functions, values clauses, table variables or temp tables. There's no reason I can see why you actually need dynamic SQL here, either, since you can bind values into your XQueries using [sql:column(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-column) and [sql:variable(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable).